Has anyone ever found a fix for the "limited quests in radar" bug?
Fallout 3, Fallout: New Vegas, Fallout 4, and Skyrim all suffered from the same bug: if you have too many active quests, new ones completely stop showing up on the radar and overworld until you complete some of the older ones.  This bug has singlehandedly discouraged me from finishing all of these games.
Has there ever been a fix for this bug for any of these games?
Even if the fix is only for one of them, since they all run on the same engine, I'm thinking it might be possible to port it.

... Maybe stop accepting that much of quests? I honestly didn't know this bug. I sometimes accept many(IMO) quests (like 10 or so), but never experienced this. In what number does this happen? Why'd you load up that much of quests?

You are talking about the HUD compass markers and the floating world markers, I take it? It doesn't sound like a bug, though, but like a way to lower memory use and CPU power (so a technical feature).

Isn't this a too broad question? You are asking about 4 different games

I spent too many hours playing all four of those games. I don't recall that being a problem.

Bethesda be like "wait, there are bugs in our games? First time we're hearing about this"

You can select which quests are visible in some of these games; but in general I'm not sure how this discourages completing the game.

I try to keep a fairly low number of quests on my to-do list, and have fewer of them actually picked to be active and marked on the map/compass in Skyrim. Partly that is just me figuring if I took a quest I really should do it at some point. But, again in Skyrim, one just deslects quests on the quest menu if there are too many pointers. Once in a quest dungeon I downselect to just that one quest so I'm not being 'directed' back to the entrance to do some other quest.
